# ASP.Net Core MVC date input value

Tags: entity-framework, date, input, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a edit view for a EF Model and have a problem with the datepicker.
Whenever i try to edit a `dataset, the edit view don't show me the old date values.

This is my Edit.cshtml Code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="BestellungsDatum" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="BestellungsDatum" type="date" class="form- control" value="@Model.BestellungsDatum" /> 
    <span asp-validation-for="BestellungsDatum" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like, but there have to be the old value at this position:

[image]

When i change the input to type="text", the value is shown but there is no datepicker.. Any solutions on this?

[image]

Comment: You are generating the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (which is not supported in all browsers) which means you must use ISO format - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097748/date-does-not-display-from-model-on-html-input-type-date/31097864#31097864)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`type="date"` generates the browsers HTML-5 datepicker if supported. The specifications require that the value be formatted in ISO format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) which is then displayed in accordance with the browsers culture.

Add the `asp-format` to format the value, and remove the `value` attribute (Tag Helpers correctly generate the `value` attribute for correct 2-way model binding and you should never attempt to add it yourself)

```
<input asp-for="BestellungsDatum" type="date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" class="form-control" />
```

Note the HTML-5 datepicker is not supported in IE, and only in recent versions of FireFox. If you want a consistent UI, then consider using a jQuery datepicker instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! This help me a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Just like to add an addition to the accepted answer:

```
<input asp-for="BestellungsDatum" type="date" class="form-control" />
```

Rather than adding `asp-format` to the view, add `DataFormatString` to the data Model or ViewModel, so you don't have to add it to every view that uses it:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime BestellungsDatum { get; set; }
```