# Localized date format with ASP.Net-Core and IE11

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, formatting, internet-explorer-11

I'm using Asp.Net Core and generate a form by using the **asp-for** feature.
My problem is the date formatted input field in IE 11. I understood that the source of the problem is missing support of HTML5 features in IE 11 (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51041551/9122330).

Because all of my users will only use one specific dateformat it would be ok to hard code it (until they change to a newer browser).

Code below is the origin version of date field:

```xml
<input asp-for="@MyClass.MyDate" class="form-control" />
```

I updated it to this code:

```xml
<input asp-for="@MyClass.MyDate" asp-format="{0:dd-yyyy-MM}" class="form-control" />
```

Now the date is correctly printed in IE 11. But in Chrome the date no longer works.
So I tried to check on server-side if IE or an other browser is in use:

```cs
<!-- IE11 -->
@if (Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString().Contains("Trident/"))
{
    <input asp-for="@MyClass.MyDate" asp-format="{0:dd-yyyy-MM}" class="form-control" />
}
else
{
    <input asp-for="@MyClass.MyDate" class="form-control" />
}
```

That code works but it feels wrong for me to code so much for each date-field.

Has anyone a suggestion for a better solution? 
Maybee centralize the if-else block to a tag helper?

And does anyone know why IE11 is not well supported in dot.net core?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there's no way to make the `date`/`datetime`/`datetime-local` input types compatible both in modern browsers and something like IE11.

Modern browsers will of course render the input correctly, with a browser control for selecting the date/time, but the value *must* be provided in ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DD`), any value not in this format is treated as null, and will result in the field not having a predefined value. Of course, if you do that, then in a browser like IE 11, the control will be rendered as a regular text input, and the user will literally see the value formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`. If you change the format to better display for IE users, then it will be invalid for modern browsers.

As a result, you have three options:

1. Just show it as `YYYY-MM-DD` in IE11. IE users will not get nicely formatted dates.
2. Render it as a text input in *all* browsers (i.e. `<input asp-for="Foo" type="text" />`, and then use a JavaScript-based calendar control to progressively enhance it for all browsers.
3. Use IE conditional comments and/or feature detection in JavaScript, to dynamically make the input type "text" and apply a custom JavaScript-based calendar control only in IE. In modern browsers, it will remain typed as "date" or whatever, and the native control will be used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know an elegant way not to check for browser-version on each date-field? Is it possible to extend the default behaviour of the "asp-for" tag-helper? Or is it required to implement my own tag-helper? I want that for IE "asp-format" tag-helper is added automatically.

Comment: You will need to handle any IE-specific stuff client side.