# Date range filter in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: filter, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, date-range

Can't populate date inputs from my model in ASP.NET Core MVC.
It's accepted, but no display dates in input after filter submit
Here's the code :

In model class:

```
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

In the view:

```
<span>Date after: </span><input type="date" name="startDate" id="startDate" asp-route-filterString="@Model.FilterString" class="form-control" value="@Model.StartDate"/>
<span>Date before: </span><input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate" asp-route-filterString="@Model.FilterString" class="form-control" value="@Model.EndDate"/>
```

In controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(...,
           string filterString,
           DateTime? startDate = null,
           DateTime? endDate = null,)
{
    // ...
    var model = new ViewModel(...)
                    {
                        StartDate = startDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        EndDate = endDate.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        // ... more code
                        FilterString = filterString,
                    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I believe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041234/asp-net-core-mvc-date-input-value

Comment: no, yo link is about editing the model. I need to filter the items on the page by date range filter with saving inputs values frm model. "asp-for" isn't workin

Comment: You said that the problem is that the date inputs (`<input type="date" />`) are not populated with the value sent from model, so the inputs stay empty, right?

Comment: yes, but the model value was set from the selected value

Comment: Try `value="@Model.EndDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")"` instead of `value="@Model.EndDate"`

Comment: yes, I forgot about the null value "EndDate?" Thanks. Put this to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 input with `type="date"` expects the value to be a specific format which is `yyyy-MM-dd`. You need set this format to the values and it will work:

```
<input type="date" asp-for="EndDate" value="@Model.EndDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
```