# Formatting Date in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to format a date in my view. In my application, I have an **Edit** button. Once clicked on, the text box becomes editable with the date value. However, it is also showing me the time, which I don't want to see. How can I fix that?

[image: Application]

[image: The Problem with the Application]

The code in my Model Class:

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
 public DateTime? Planned_Date { get; set; }
```

The code in my View class:

```
<td class="Planned_Date">
    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>item.Planned_Date)</span>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => item.Planned_Date)
</td>
```

The onClick():

```
  $("body").on("click", "#tblCustomers .Edit", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                    $(this).find("input").show();
                    $(this).find("span").hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Update").show();
            row.find(".Cancel").show();
            $(this).hide();
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your `DataAnnotation` on your model.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

Add in the `ApplyInEditMode` property:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"), ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

This will make the `DataFormartString` be applied to textboxes generated with `EditorFor`, or other editors. From this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application),

> The ApplyFormatInEditMode setting specifies that the specified
>   formatting should also be applied when the value is displayed in a
>   text box for editing. (You might not want that for some fields — for
>   example, for currency values, you might not want the currency symbol
>   in the text box for editing.)

Then, instead of declaring the input element in your view and setting the value from the model, you should update your view to use the Razor helper, `Html.EditorFor`. Refer to the [Microsoft API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ee834942(v=vs.118)) for more information.

```
<td class="Planned_Date">
    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(x=>item.Planned_Date)</span>
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>item.Planned_Date)  
</td>
```

You may have to adjust the example code to fit your situation (for example, adding classes or styles). Your JavaScript should still work.

Note: The `DisplayFormat` `DataAnnotation` does not apply to inputs generated with `Html.TextboxFor`. It only applies to textboxes (or other editors) generated with `Html.EditorFor` and Razor Display helpers.

Comment: I still see the time..

Comment: Could you update your question with your updated model and view?

Comment: Made the changes

Comment: Refer to the updated answer and try Html.EditorFor instead of Html.TextboxFor. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you @Jack, worked like a charm!

Comment: Incorrect! It must be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format) to work with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and `EditorFor()`. Refer [Date does not display from Model on HTML input type date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097748/date-does-not-display-from-model-on-html-input-type-date/31097864#31097864)