# Format date in a View in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I make the date format to be `"dd.MM.yyyy"` because whatever I do it is always `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

View part:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 pull-left">
    <label asp-for="@Model.RequestRegistrationDateFrom"></label>
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.RequestRegistrationDateFrom" class="form-control js-datepicker pull-left" />
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <span class="input-group-text calendar-fa"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Model property:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy")]
[Display(Name = "Date from", ResourceType = typeof(string))]
public DateTime? RequestRegistrationDateFrom { get; set; }
```

Comment: `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` generates `type="date"` which will display the browsers HTML5 datepicker with the date in the browsers culture (and you would need to add `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` to `[DisplayFormat]` and use ISO format - refer [Date does not display from Model on HTML input type date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31097748/date-does-not-display-from-model-on-html-input-type-date/31097864#31097864) for more details.

Comment: If you do not want the browsers HTML5 datepicker, then remove the `[DataType]` attribute and add `asp-format="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"` to the `<input>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke both approaches don't work :(

Comment: Then you have not done it correctly or have other issues as well

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have heard such case as you are experiencing. Unfortunately, I haven't got it myself, and haven't got a chance to dig into what's actually wrong behind DisplayFormat attribute.

In that case, passing formatted string to value attribute worked.

```
<input type="text" asp-for="RequestRegistrationDateFrom" value="@Model.RequestRegistrationDateFrom.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")" class="form-control js-datepicker pull-left" />
```

Try it for now. Hopefully, it would work in your case too.

If you could post a solution here when you figure out the problem behind, that'll be awesome. I'm interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple bro, just do the following:

[DataType(DataType.Date)]

public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Today;

Comment: How can it be shown as `"dd.MM.yyyy"` then?

Answer (score 0):

In your model:

```cs
[Column(TypeName = "Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
```

In your view:

```html
<td>@item.start_date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
```